# wildcard in .screenrc chdir

Tags: linux, wildcard, gnu-screen

I'm trying to build a `.screenrc` that fits my needs.
For this I want to do a `chdir` to a directory of which I don't know the exact name.
In Bash I'd just do

```
cd /path/to/some-V4.3.*/sub/directory/
```

to enter that 4.3.x directory that currently exists while there can only be one.
Now how, if at all, can I do this in `.screenrc`?

```
chdir /path/to/some-V4.3.*/sub/directory/
```

does not work, it tells me that this directory does not exist because the wildcard is not expanded.